# Is it possible to install Erlang R16 on OSX 10.9 via homebrew?

Tags: macos, erlang, homebrew

I have a clean OSX 10.9 box and I have tried to install R16 erlang via homebrew:

```
brew install erlang
```

Unfortunately, that installs R17. So I tried to install it via "versions" recipes:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew update
brew doctor
brew install erlang-r16
```

Surprisingly, this fails with error:

```
Error: No available formula for erlang-r16
```

Is it any way to install Erlang R16 right now via homebrew or I need to wait a few months before recipes/repository/whatever is correctly updated and synchronized?

Comment: How about using kerl - http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/erlang/#Install-using-kerl?

Comment: @mkorszun From page you linked: "You can install Erlang in several ways on OS X: from source, with Homebrew, or with MacPorts." - no kerl option for OSX as it seems to me :(

Comment: I have OSX and I am using kerl - and it works great! Just try it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise you to download source of any release you like/need the most.

I installed Erlang/OTP r17(otp_src_17.0) from sources on OSX 10.9.3.

Everything works ok. Even GUI observer.

However you might need to install graphical libraries needed by observer. If I did so, I used sources as well.

Good luck!